# How to fix this?

Tags: python

How do I fix this? I know that the error is in line 8 (g = f/5) but how do i fix the error?

```
a = input("Enter a number: ")
b = input("Enter a second number: ")
c = input("Enter a third number: ")
d = input("Enter a fourth number: ")
e = input("Enter a fifth number: ")

f = a+b+c+d+e
g = f/5

print  ("The average of these numbers is "+str(g))
```

Comment: Take a look at  [ask]

Comment: What is the error that is given? Also, StackOverflow is about asking specifc questions, not posting code and asking people how to fix it

Comment: If the error is on `g` then my best guess would be the division gives an integer, you can change to : `g=float(f)/5`. But then we can only guess with so little information given

Answer (score 2):

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: ")) #if you want user to allow non-integer number tan use float instead of int
b = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
c = int(input("Enter a third number: "))
d = int(input("Enter a fourth number: "))
e = int(input("Enter a fifth number: "))

f = a+b+c+d+e
g = f/5

print  ("The average of these numbers is "+str(g))
```

In python by default input is taken as string and when you add two string `56`and `4` it will just give you another string `564` which is concatenate but you can not divide string hence you got error on that line.